# Best way to send rating data to backend service or email

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am busy making an *Ionic app* in which I'll ask feedback of my users via a rating module. I want to get the **value of the rating and send it in a form**....

My question would be: how to send this in a form? Should I use `PHP`? Should I use something `Angular` provides? I *Googled* but couldn't find one good answer.

I'd appreciate a brief example / snippet of a simple form that does this (I already have the rating values) and I'd prefer using Angular over anything else, but I don't know if that's possible.

The only thing I need to do is either send the values back to the backend or to an external email address.

Comment: Software recommendation questions are *[off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* here on [so]. Perhaps you should ask over at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) of the Stackexchange network. Make sure you *do* look at their [help center](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ionic, use angleJS $http to send form data in the Ionic , and then through the form of PHP to receive data processing.

```
angular.module('Ctrl', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.form_data = {};

    $scope.send = function() {

        var data = {
            form_data_1: $scope.form_data.theme,
            form_data_2: $scope.form_data.score,
        }

        var url = "http://php.api.com/";

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: url
        }).
        then(function(response) {
            // PHP Response
        }, function(response) {
            // Failed
        });

    };

})
```